# Trying to use split() on stdin in python

Tags: python, split

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.read() :
    numbers = line.split()
    print numbers
```

I have been trying to figure out what is going on when I am using split() in python.  Based on what I've read, with no arguments, it splits on white space, and it splits the line into a list of strings. 
When I run this (tiny) snippet of code (using this to try to figure out what is going wrong in a larger program) with input similar to

```
1 100
2 32
3 76
```

I get :

```
['1']
[]
['1']
['0']
['0']
[]
['2']
[]
['3']
['2']
[]
['3']
[]
['7']
['6']
[]
```

I have tried a couple of arguments in split(), including (' '), and no argument as well as ('\n') to see if I can figure out why it is splitting each element into individual characters.  I also tried using input of two separate words per line, and got similar output.

So, my question is : why is this splitting after each character rather than on white space?

Comment: problem is not split problem is reading input char by char

Comment: It is not the `split` that the problem is. You iterate over the *result* of a `read()` which is a string. So you iterate over the characters.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes much more sense.  I actually just had it print after the for line above and now I can see it.  I will have to look for something other than read() to handle the input.  I took off the read() and I think that it is heading in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in sys.stdin.read() :
```

`sys.stdin` is an input stream. By using `read()` you're reading the input as a string. Iterating on a string yields single chars, not lines. So `line` is a char. Which explains that `split` doesn't work / has no effect.

fix is just iterating on `stdin`, which yields line by line:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    numbers = line.split()
    print numbers
```